# ASP.Net: Login control, LoginUser_LoggedIn, and Role population

Tags: asp.net, security, roles

I have a forms based application. The application is standard ASP.Net wizard generated with login controls. The root's `web.config` appears to be in order for forms based authentication. I did have to change the `<roleManager>` element to use `type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"` (rather than a Windows token) per [How To: Use Role Manager in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647401.aspx).

I have setup three roles - Administrators, Engineers, Customers. There are three users - admin (administrator), eddie (engineer), and cathy (customer). I have verified the users and their roles using ASP.Net Configuration Tool.

Each role has its own directory on disk, and each role has its own collection of ASPX files and 'landing page'. Each directory has a `web.config` to limit access to the role in question. For example:

```
<location path="~/Engineers">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Engineers" />
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Upon successful login, I hook `LoginUser_LoggedIn` to write a destination URL. The problem I am having is the user's roles are not populated upon login, so I'm not getting a good redirect. In the code below, `rolesArray` has a zero size.

Any ideas? Should I be approaching this from a different angle?

```
Private Sub LoginUser_LoggedIn(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles LoginUser.LoggedIn

    Try
        Dim rolesArray() As String
        rolesArray = Roles.GetRolesForUser()
        Debug.Assert(rolesArray.Length > 0)

        If (Roles.IsUserInRole("Administrators") = True) Then
            LoginUser.DestinationPageUrl = "~/Administrators/Dashboard.aspx"
        ElseIf (Roles.IsUserInRole("Engineers") = True) Then
            LoginUser.DestinationPageUrl = "~/Engineers/Workspace.aspx"
        ElseIf (Roles.IsUserInRole("Customers") = True) Then
            LoginUser.DestinationPageUrl = "~/Customers/Dashboard.aspx"
        Else
            Debug.Assert(False)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Print(ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same request upon logging in, the cookie is not available for use (for instance, if you check `this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`, it returns false too).  It's because the cookie is established during that request, and will be available upon subsequent requests.

I'd recommend redirecting to a common page, then doing this check and redirect again, or query the roles directly from the database using the user Id of the login control.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I just figured out that User.IsAuthenticated is False for a logged in user. Odd to say the least.

Comment: @noloader Not really, when you think that the code to initialize that probably happens during init or so time, and the logged in event fires after load, handles the response, checks the membership, and write the ticket.  That's probably why, and why it's available on the next postback.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. A successful login now takes a user to `LoginSuccess.aspx`. On the `LoginSuccess.aspx` page, the `User._username` is vaild. Unfortunately, `User._roles` is still empty, so my role based redirect fails. Both `Roles.IsUserInRole` and `User.IsInRole` provide bad information. I did notice that `User.IsRoleListCached` is true (and the role provider is `SqlRoleProvider`). Is there a way to force an update of the role list (I did not see it via IntelliSense)?

Comment: I'm not sure... try adding a call to Roles.GetRolesForUser("username") method call, and see what comes back in loginsuccess.aspx

Comment: This is bizzare. I just checked the roles I set up earlier via ASP.Net Configuration Tool. No roles are defined??? After re-adding the roles, the role based redirection worked. I'm not even going to ask where the roles went....

Comment: You do have <authentication mode="forms"> present? or is this windows forms authentication?